# Authenticate User for Win 10 UWP

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, uwp, win-universal-app

I need to authenticate a user to my UWP app to get onlineidauthenticator.AuthenticatedSafeCustomerId since I haven't authenticated the user `AuthenticatedSafeCustomerId` is coming as empty. Anyone please help me to authenticate user. I am new. I wrote the following code for Microsoft login. But it breaks at authenticate User. anyone knows the reason?

```
var targetArray = new List<OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest>();
targetArray.Add(new OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest("jsonwebtokensample.com", "JWT"));

try
{
    _authenticator = new OnlineIdAuthenticator();
    var result = await _authenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync(targetArray, CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded);

    if (result.Tickets[0].Value != string.Empty)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        // errors are to be handled here.
    }
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    // errors are to be handled here.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [OnlineIdAuthenticator class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.authentication.onlineid.onlineidauthenticator.aspx) for Microsoft login, you must associate the app with the Windows Store.

To associate your app with the Windows Store, open your app's project file in Visual Studio:

1. From the **Store** menu, select **Associate App with the Store...**
   [image]
2. Click **Sign in** to sign into your Windows Store developer account using your Microsoft account credentials. If you don't have a Windows Store developer account, go to your [**Windows Store Dashboard**](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=233762) to create one, and then restart this procedure.
3. Select the app from the list with which you want to associate your app in Visual Studio. If the app is not listed, click **Reserve name** to add it to your Windows Store developer account.
4. Click **Next** to review the info that the wizard will add to your app.
5. If the info looks correct, click **Associate** and the wizard will update your app's package manifest.

After associating, you can authenticate user with Microsoft Account.